# Custom Cells Not Populating Correct Data When Off-Screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Forgive the naive nature of this question, but despite my searching here, I can't quite find a solution.

In my project, I have a UITableView with custom cells, all of which are populated by data from an API.  At this point, based on the desired design, four of the cells are visible on-screen at launch, and I have to scroll to see the other four.  Each cell has two components; a label and a UIView, which is generating a line chart.  The first four cells all work properly, but the second set of cells (which are off-screen at loading) populate the label correct, but the UIView is not showing the correct set of data (it is populating with previously used data).

Oddly, if I tap on one of the problematic cells, the cell immediately reloads with the correct data.

For context, here's part of my TableViewController;

```
...
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return minions.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return minionCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}

    func minionCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> MinionCell {
        let minion = minions[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(minionCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MinionCell

        if let name = minion.name {

            cell.nameLabel?.text = minion.name ?? "Minion"
            cell.lineChart?.graphPoints = minion.bandwidth ?? [1,2,3,4,5]
        } else {
            cell.nameLabel?.text = "No data available."
            cell.lineChart?.graphPoints = [1,2,3,4,5]
        }
        return cell
    }
...
```

Is it possible that I need to somehow "pre-render" the off-screen cells at load?  Again, sorry for the naive nature.

As always, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you most probably know, cells that go off screen get reused for the new rows. That is why the new rows come with the old graphs. The fact that if you tap the cell the graph refreshes and is correctly displayed makes me think that it is a drawing problem. Try triggering a force redraw by calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the view with the graph:

```
cell.lineChart?.graphPoints = [1,2,3,4,5]
cell.lineChart?.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: That did the trick!  I wasn't even aware of the `setNeedsDisplay` code, but I looked it up and understand now.  Thank you very much, @skyddict!  Will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat skeptical about your function `minionCellAtIndexPath`.

The reason you are getting older data again, and not newer is probably because you are not resetting it. 
Before your `if let` checks, set hardcoded values, the ones that you are setting in your else. and then run again.